# Should "BI Center Site" be used for any areas that will include a mixture of data content

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, site-collection, business-intelligence, sql-server-2012

We have a SP farm set up and it is in it's infancy.

Our department is BI.

There are 10 products within our company, each with different management and BI needs, therefore we'd like to create a site for each of these products.

Should we use a [BI Center site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/what-is-a-business-intelligence-center-HA104046023.aspx) as a template for each of these 10 sites ?

Comment: what version and edition of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: @SupriyoSBChatterjee pretty sure we've got one of the latest versions (2012?) definitely Enterprise

Comment: the versions & editions have varying features & capabilities

Comment: @SupriyoSBChatterjee Ok - we're using 2013 Enterprise

Comment: what version of SQL are you using? Part of the BI stack relies on this as well

Comment: @AndersRask edited tags `SQL-Server-2012`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create One BI Center for Each Product,its easy to manager( i am assuming each Product having Different set of users).

But [Configuring the BI][1] is more tricky...Couple of things you should make sure.

1. [Plan it properly](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee683867.aspx)
2. [Mapping User License](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219627.aspx)
3. [Creating the Secure Store Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/fp142398.aspx)
4. Properly Configuration of Excel Services, Performance Point and
   Visio

Comment: yes - we have different users for each product

Comment: what does this mean "But [Configuring the BI][1] is more tricky" ...or is it just some strange formatting?

Answer (score 2):

You have excellent environment for BI platform with SQL 2012 and SharePoint 2013 enterprise edition.

So my strong recommendation would be to please extend the BI site template to all the other 10 products and make sure you activate the SharePoint enterprise features so that you will be able to utilize the core SharePoint collaboration features along with BI.

A bunch of other features that you would also need is managed metadata services and so on.

Coming back to BI tools currently excel services is the key which can be widely used for either graphical data interpretations or to pull data from the external data sources using pivot tables/power views for all your 10 product sites.

Comment: is Power View part of SP 2013 Enterprise?

Comment: power view is an add on for SSRS and is not part of sharepoint installation.

Comment: +1....so a little confused: you say "....pull data from the external data sources using pivot tables/power views". Power View isn't really part of Excel Services is it - I thought it was pretty much stand alone - or will I be able to embed graphics from Power View **into** Excel Services dashboards?

Comment: check this technet, will give you more detail about the BI....ECS< Power View, Performance Point, PowerPivot etc   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/fp142398.aspx

Comment: @kesava in terms of "make sure you activate the SharePoint enterprise features" does this need to be done for each site - or because I 'm using the BI site template I assume provisions have already been made within the template for our needs re. SSRS, XL services etc.

Comment: by default, it wont be activated so we need to activate them manually.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you can use single BI Center site template to manage content for all 10 products site.

In one single BI Center site you can show multiple content of multiple products using score-cards, dashboards, excel BI reports, SQL reporting services reports, PerformancePoint reports, Chart web-parts, etc.

You need to do a little home work and understand the capabilities that is offered in BI in SharePoint. You will find good resources over the web and enough video and presentation tutorials to kick start your learning.

Comment: think I'm favouring multiple BI Center Sites ...one for each product. Doesn't seem like there will be a massive overhead of taking that route.